# How Symfony 4 generate Key Names in Migrations?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have eg.:

```
CREATE TABLE news
(...)
INDEX IDX_1DD399507E3C61F9 (owner_id)
```

And:

```
ALTER TABLE news 
(...)
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1DD399507E3C61F9 FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES user (id)
```

I mean, how the names: `IDX_1DD399507E3C61F9` and `FK_1DD399507E3C61F9` are generated?

I want to add more manually and I would like to keep same strategy.

Is this random or parameterized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [file](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.9/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/Table.html#method_addIndex) at the method `addIndex()` for example. This one is responsible for generating your `IDX_1DD399507E3C61F9` index.

See more at the source code on the [github repository](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/2.9/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/Table.php#L129)

```
$indexName = $this->_generateIdentifierName(
    array_merge([$this->getName()], $columnNames),
    'idx',
    $this->_getMaxIdentifierLength()
);
```

This snippet calls the `_generateIdentifierName()` method of the parent class `AbstractAsset` which you could inherit from, too.

```
protected function _generateIdentifierName($columnNames, $prefix = '', $maxSize = 30)
{
    $hash = implode('', array_map(static function ($column) {
        return dechex(crc32($column));
    }, $columnNames));

    return strtoupper(substr($prefix . '_' . $hash, 0, $maxSize));
}
```